# MISRA C: 2004 Rule 5.5 (advisory): No object or function identifier with static storage duration should be reused

Tags: c, misra

I have the second violation found by Understand SciTools, but I have no clear the right action to correct the violation.

The violation regards the `Rule 5.5 (advisory): No object or function identifier with static storage duration should be reused` in the following code, in particular `Static Identifier 'x' reused`

```
 /* llvalue -> ICmp.t option */
CAMLprim value llvm_instr_icmp_predicate(LLVMValueRef Val) {
  CAMLparam0();
  int x = LLVMGetICmpPredicate(Val);
  if (x) {
    value Option = alloc(1, 0);
    Field(Option, 0) = Val_int(x - LLVMIntEQ);
    CAMLreturn(Option);
  }
  CAMLreturn(Val_int(0));
}

/* llvalue -> FCmp.t option */
CAMLprim value llvm_instr_fcmp_predicate(LLVMValueRef Val) {
  CAMLparam0();
  int x = LLVMGetFCmpPredicate(Val);
  if (x) {
    value Option = alloc(1, 0);
    Field(Option, 0) = Val_int(x - LLVMRealPredicateFalse);
    CAMLreturn(Option);
  }
  CAMLreturn(Val_int(0));
}
```

Comment: My first impression is that the declaration of the variable `x` in the statements `int x = …` is reusing a global static variable `x` that is visible in this code. The first step would be to rename the local variable `x` to some other name such as `xLocal`. Does your IDE allow you to locate a variable by clicking on it and finding its definition?

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere in your project, you have another variable named `x`, with static storage duration. Not necessarily in the same translation unit where you get the MISRA violation.

This was always a silly rule, I would create a permanent deviation organization-wide and ignore it. (It's an advisory rule)

On the other hand, `x` is a horrible variable name.

Comment: In fact, the likelihood is quite high that the other, static `x` is not in the same translation unit, for otherwise I would expect the checker to instead, or at least additionally, report a violation of rule 5.2: "Identifiers in an inner scope shall not use the same name as an 
identifier in an outer scope, and therefore hide that identifier."

Comment: @JohnBollinger True. That one is a far more sensible rule to follow.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin I agree, x is an horrible variable name. The code is not mine, I am doing revision with MISRA C: 2004 rule on another code.